# ¿Cómo anidar dos if y que se cumplan ambas condiciones?

Tags: php, condiciones

Tengo una condición la hora de recibido de una factura debe estar dentro de las 8:30 y 1:30 si esta dentro de ese rango, la hora de entrega no debe pasar de las 6:00 del día que se facturo , pero no se como anidar un `if` y que entre otra condición para que ambas se cumplan.

Este es el código:

```
<?php
  include('conexion.php');
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT factura, fechafactura, cliente, hrasalida, hraentrega, hrallegada,fechaentrega,horarecibido, chofer, vehiculo, direccion from facturacion where estatus='ENTREGA DOMICILIO' order by fechafactura DESC LIMIT 70");
  $cont=mysql_num_rows($query);
  if ($cont>0)
  {
    while ($array=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $fefac=$array[1];
      $feent=$array[6];
      $recfac=$array[7];
      $hrini=$array[3];
      $hrfin=$array[4];
      $diferencias = strtotime($hrfin) - strtotime($hrini); 
      $mins=$diferencias/60;        
      $horalimite=strtotime("18:00:00");
      $hentrega=strtotime($hrfin);
      //$fechafac=strtotime($fefac);
      //$fechaent=strtotime($feent);
      $hora1=strtotime("08:30:00");
      $hora2=strtotime("01:30:00");         
      $hrecfac=strtotime($recfac);
      if($hrecfac>=$hora1 && $hrecfac<=$hora2) 
      {  
       if($hentrega>$horalimite or strtotime($feent)>strtotime($fefac)) 
       {
         $status="FUERA DE TIEMPO";
       }else{
         $status="A TIEMPO";
       }
      }else{

      }
      echo'<tr><td>'.$array[0].'</td><td>'.$array[1].'</td><td>'.$array[2].'</td><td>'.$array[3].'</td><td>'.$array[4].'</td><td>'.$array[5].'</td><td>'.$array[6].'</td><td>'.$array[7].'</td><td>'.$array[8].'</td><td>'.$array[9].'</td><td>'.$array[10].'</td><td>'.$mins.' minutos'. '</td><td>'.$status.'</td></tr>';
    }
}

else
{
    echo'<tr><td>No hay registros</td></tr>';
}
echo '<table>';
/***************************************TERMINA FACTURAS*/
?>
```

Comment: Hola @jasiel, necesitamos que estructures un poco el código. Es un poco difícil de leer tal y como lo presentas.

Comment: Puede ser if(condicion1!="" && condicion2!="") Aca uso el operador "AND"->&& "OR"->||

Comment: si pensé en meter las dos condiciones en un if pero me afecta el resultado , quiero que primero identifique si esta dentro del rango de horas y si esta entre a la siguiente condición para determinas si esta a tiempo o fuera de tiempo

Comment: Que tal si preguntas por la condicion 1 y si se cumple asignas true a una variable nueva. Creas la otra condicion sin anidar, ni dentro del primer if y preguntas si isset($var1) y tu condicion, con eso garantizas que haya pasado la primera condición y que haga lo que desees si pasa la 2da

Comment: no entendí muy bien tu explicación me podrías poner la sintaxis del orden de las condiciones

Comment: Tienes comentadas, dos lineas:  //$fechafac=strtotime($fefac);
      //$fechaent=strtotime($feent); te habias percatado de ello?,  con ello no se efectua el condicional correspondiente, tambien considero que en el penultimo "ELSE" deberias agregar: $status="FUERA DE TIEMPO";

Comment: las lineas comentadas es código que por el momento no voy a usar , y si están comentadas no afecta a la ejecución del código no ? , y si le agregue la variable que me comentas al else, pero aun así no funciona no se como hacer para que si se cumple el primer if ejecute el segundo